# How can we write an optimal function to get alphabetical sequence for a given number?

Tags: javascript, java, php, algorithm, functional-programming

I want a function like

```
string getAlphabetEncoding(num){
    //some logic
    return strForNum;
}
```

input: 1 output: a, input: 5 output: e, input: 27 output: aa, input: 676 output: YZ, input: 677 output: za...

Comment: javascript, java and php?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Tushar: It's the way spreadsheet programs such as Excel label their columns. The first 26 numbers are represented by single-letter names, the next 26x26 numbers by two-letter names and so on.

Comment: I think that the value for AAA should be 703, not 677. (The representation is not a true base 26 representation.)

Comment: @M Oehm Thanks for correcting the values, i posted in hurry :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try:

```js
var ABC = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";

function getNameFromNumber(num) {
  var numeric = (num - 1) % 26;
  var letter = ABC[numeric];
  var num2 = parseInt((num - 1) / 26);
  if (num2 > 0) {
    return getNameFromNumber(num2) + '' + letter;
  } else {
    return letter;
  }
}

var data = document.getElementById('data');
data.innerHTML += 1 + ' ->  ' + getNameFromNumber(1) + '<br>'; //A
data.innerHTML += 5 + ' ->  ' + getNameFromNumber(5) + '<br>'; //E
data.innerHTML += 27 + ' ->  ' + getNameFromNumber(27) + '<br>'; //AA
data.innerHTML += 676 + ' ->  ' + getNameFromNumber(676) + '<br>'; //YZ
data.innerHTML += 677 + ' ->  ' + getNameFromNumber(677) + '<br>'; //ZA
```

```html
<div id=data></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to convert from Base 10 to Bijective Base 26 (spreadsheet column notation), otherwise known as the hexavigesimal system.

You list JavaScript as a language of interest, so I have targeted it. The code below performs that conversion, but note that the outputs are not what you suggest in your question. I have verified them with my spreadsheet program and found them to be correct, so I am assuming the values in our question are wrong.

```
Number.prototype.toBijectiveBase26 = (function () {
  return function toBijectiveBase26() {
    n = this
    ret = "";
    while(parseInt(n)>0){
      --n;
      ret += String.fromCharCode("A".charCodeAt(0)+(n%26));
      n/=26;
    }
    return ret.split("").reverse().join("");
  };
}());

Number(1).toBijectiveBase26();   //Returns A
Number(5).toBijectiveBase26();   //Returns E
Number(27).toBijectiveBase26();  //Returns AA
Number(676).toBijectiveBase26(); //Returns YZ
Number(677).toBijectiveBase26(); //Returns ZA
```